# Is there a synonym for "satisfied customer" or "one who can testify"?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, business-language

For example, I wish to borrow a book from someone. In order to assure that person that I will treat their book carefully, I want to refer them to someone I have already borrowed a book from in the past who knows that I am responsible.

What is the word for that person who can recommend me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such a person is *[reference](http://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=reference)*:

> **reference**, *noun* : A person who is in a position to recommend another or to vouch for his or her fitness.

Comment: I guess this would work in some situations, but I was looking for a word that could be used more informally...

Comment: Most synonyms (backer, guarantor, patron) are _more_ formal, not less; unless you want go with something like _buddy_ or _mate_.

Comment: It seems like there should be a more efficient way to say 'someone to vouch for me.' I was looking for a term that would be used in everyday speech (outside of strictly business contexts), but perhaps there is none other than 'buddy' or 'mate' or the like.

Comment: Is this perhaps the original meaning of a *reference librarian*? She knows you have borrowed and returned books in the past, so she vouches that you will do so in the future. (My wife was a reference librarian years ago and thinks this is one of the few decent jokes I have come up with in years. :-)

Comment: @PeterRowell Heh; my wife has the same opinion of my jokes.

Comment: When I use "reference" outside of a business context, it means "character reference" to most people, which seems to be what you're after. Or you can just say, "My next-door neighbor can vouch for me."

Answer (score 0):

Since such a person would be attesting to your reliability, perhaps some form of *one who attests* might work, e.g., *attestant*, *attester*, or *attestator*.

Otherwise, there are a few legal terms you could choose from if you didn't mind raising a few eyebrows, e.g., *deponent*, *cojuror*, and *compurgator*.